# How do I correctly use Keras Embedding layer?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, deep-learning, neural-network

I have written the following multi-input Keras TensorFlow model:

```
CHARPROTLEN = 25 #size of vocab
CHARCANSMILEN = 62 #size of vocab

protein_input = Input(shape=(train_protein.shape[1:]))
compound_input = Input(shape=(train_smile.shape[1:]))

#protein layers
x = Embedding(input_dim=CHARPROTLEN+1,output_dim=128, input_length=maximum_amino_acid_sequence_length) (protein_input)
x = Conv1D(filters=32, padding="valid", activation="relu", strides=1, kernel_size=4)(x)
x = Conv1D(filters=64, padding="valid", activation="relu", strides=1, kernel_size=8)(x)
x = Conv1D(filters=96, padding="valid", activation="relu", strides=1, kernel_size=12)(x)
final_protein = GlobalMaxPooling1D()(x)

#compound layers
y = Embedding(input_dim=CHARCANSMISET+1,output_dim=128, input_length=maximum_SMILES_length) (compound_input)
y = Conv1D(filters=32, padding="valid", activation="relu", strides=1, kernel_size=4)(y)
y = Conv1D(filters=64, padding="valid", activation="relu", strides=1, kernel_size=6)(y)
y = Conv1D(filters=96, padding="valid", activation="relu", strides=1, kernel_size=8)(y)
final_compound = GlobalMaxPooling1D()(y)

join = tf.keras.layers.concatenate([final_protein, final_compound], axis=-1)


x = Dense(1024, activation="relu")(join)
x = Dropout(0.1)(x)
x = Dense(1024, activation='relu')(x)
x = Dropout(0.1)(x)
x = Dense(512, activation='relu')(x)

predictions = Dense(1,kernel_initializer='normal')(x)

model = Model(inputs=[protein_input, compound_input], outputs=[predictions])
```

The inputs have the following shapes:

```
train_protein.shape
TensorShape([5411, 1500, 1])

train_smile.shape
TensorShape([5411, 100, 1])
```

I get the following error message:

```
ValueError: One of the dimensions in the output is <= 0 due to downsampling in conv1d. Consider increasing the input size. Received input shape [None, 1500, 1, 128] which would produce output shape with a zero or negative value in a dimension.
```

Is this due to the `Embedding` layer having the incorrect `output_dim`? How do I correct this? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A `Conv1D` layer requires the input shape `(batch_size, timesteps, features)`, which `train_protein` and `train_smile` already have. For example, `train_protein` consists of 5411 samples, where each sample has 1500 timesteps, and each timestep one feature. Applying an `Embedding` layer to them results in adding an additional dimension, which `Conv1D` layers cannot work with.

You have two options. You either leave out the `Embedding` layer altogether and feed your inputs directly to the `Conv1D` layers, or you reshape your data to be `(5411, 1500)` for `train_protein` and `(5411, 100)` for `train_smile`. You can use `tf.reshape`, `tf.squeeze`, or `tf.keras.layers.Reshape` to reshape the data. Afterwards you can use the `Embedding` layer as planned. And note that `output_dim` determines the n-dimensional vector to which each timestep will be mapped. See also [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69591717/how-is-the-keras-conv1d-input-specified-i-seem-to-be-lacking-a-dimension/69594400#69594400) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69996228/connect-embedding-layer-with-dimension-3-50-to-lstm).

Comment: That works. I reshaped my inputs. What are the consequences of leaving out the embedding layer when working with text data?

Comment: Did you check the links in the answer ?